# Taking the arguments and using it

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, argument-passing

Im practicing threads and i found a problem that says "Create as many threads as arguments receive the program being executed"

I.E = 
`./program a c d` (here 3 threads will be created)

I have no idea how to take the arguments and use it, can you guys teach me how i can to this? im not asking you to make me the code (some people may think im asking you to make my homework and it is not like that) thank you

Comment: You need to take a closer look at your `main` function, in particular the meaning of its arguments.

Comment: Google argc and argv.

Comment: This post isn't actually about threading. It's more of a basic C question on working with variable length argument arrays. Please trim off the threading stuff from the post.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever notice the argc and argv in the prototype of main-

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Those two variables are responsible for managing the command like arguments. `argc` or argument count stores the number of arguments received from the command line. One argument is always received which is the program's current directory. `argv[]` stores the actual arguments received. These are stored as strings in the form of array. To access, say 1st argument, you can use

```
printf("%s", argv[0]);
```

Comment: Please note that the argv[0] is always the name of the command line used to execute the program. The first user supplied argument is argv[1].